# Keys F2, F3, 2, 3, W, E, S, D, X, C not working on an old laptop keyboard

Tags: laptop, keyboard, dell-precision

The laptop is a Dell Precision M90.
Tried cleaning the connector with alcohol.
Doesn't seem to be any dust there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Failed keys in diagonal stripes, top left to bottom right, is a classic sign that the PCB is cracked. Two stripes means two tracks are broken.

Time for a new keyboard, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you, exactly the answer i needed. Thankfully there are cheap ones sold on Ebay.